Drools named consequence rule giving different outputs for the same input
My web application has an endpoint /automatic which takes a POST request, converts the request body into entity and fire the given rule against that entity.
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Cat {
    private String name;
    private String nickName;
}

import com.example.demo.entity.Cat

rule "cat rule"
when
m: Cat(name == "foo")
if (nickName == "bar") do [named_consequence]
then
System.out.println("Rule got triggered !");
then [named_consequence]
System.out.println("Named consequence got triggered !");
end

curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '
{
    "name": "foo",
    "nickName": "bar"
}
' \
    -L localhost:8080/automatic

Output:
Rule got triggered !

There is another POST endpoint /manual which manually creates the entity and fire the given rule against that entity
Cat cat = new Cat("foo", "bar");

Output:
Named consequence got triggered !
Rule got triggered !

PROBLEM: For the same entity, I'm getting two different output for the rule.
What I can see is when manually creating the entity, the if statement compares the content of the string and when creating entity using the request, the if statement compares the reference. I can simple solve the problem by modifying the if statement to:
if (nickName.equals("bar")) do [named_consequence]

But why is this happening?
Code: https://github.com/Vishesh-Mukherjee/drools
Edit:
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private DemoService demoService;

    @PostMapping("/automatic")
    public void automaticRun(@RequestBody Cat cat) {
        demoService.process(cat);
    }

    @PostMapping("/manual")
    public void manualRun() {
        Cat cat = new Cat("foo", "bar");
        demoService.process(cat);
    }

}

@Service
public class DemoService {

    private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    public void process(Cat cat) {
        System.out.println("Data: " + cat);
        kieServices.newKieBuilder(getKieFileSystem()).buildAll();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        kieSession.insert(cat);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
    }

    public KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem() {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("cat_rule.drl"));
        return kieFileSystem;
    }
}


Sounds like the issue is with how your /automatic endpoint is creating and firing the rules. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in that method and stepping through it?

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks for the reply!. I've added breakpoints, but I'm still encountering issues. I've abstracted the code for rule creation and firing into a single method called process(Cat cat). This method is being invoked from both endpoints with the exact same Cat object (Cat(name=foo, nickName=bar)), yet the endpoints are producing different results. I've updated the question with the controller and service code for reference.

When I change the dialect to mvel dialect "mvel" and add m. as a prefix to nickName in the if statement if (m.nickName == "bar") do [named_consequence], then everything is working fine. Don't know why it's not working without this modification though.
